# Can't animate a Line2D

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to animate an `imshow` object in a notebook. The code is rather long but I think this shorter sample with a `Line2D` shows the same problem. First, in case that helps, I have an alternative design which works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

series = [[3,1,1,2], [4,6,4,3], [2,6,8,7]]

def f(n):
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(series[n])

slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=len(series)-1)
widgets.interact(f, n=slider);
```

As I shouldn't need to recreate the figure and axe at each frame, my actual code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

series = [[3,1,1,2], [4,6,4,3], [2,6,8,7]]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.plot(series[0]) # Some plot is required to get a Line2D object
h = h[0] # Line2D object

def f(n):
    h.set_ydata(series[n])

slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=len(series)-1)
widgets.interact(f, n=slider);
```

This code doesn't work, the first frame is shown, but there is no update when the slider is moved. I wonder if this is related to the fact `h` is defined outside the callback function `f`, but in my actual case I've other variables defined outside the function which are correctly handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way, but you can use `IPython.display` to update the figure.

The following works for me:

```
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

series = [[3,1,1,2], [4,6,4,3], [2,6,8,7]]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.plot(series[0]) # Some plot is required to get a Line2D object
h = h[0] # Line2D object
plt.close() # Prevent normal display

def f(n):
    h.set_ydata(series[n])
    display(fig) # Display in widget
    
slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=len(series)-1)
widgets.interact(f, n=slider);
```